# Add String Input to Array Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to build an Array with 5 strings in there; indexed 0 - 4. After this I need to shuffle the different pieces in the array rounds. The problem that I'm having is that is creating 5 different arrays I think?  Could someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

To give an better understanding; this is the input of the fileScanner: 
5,4 4,5 8,7=6,3 3,2 9,6 4,3=7,6=9,8=5,5 7,8 6,5 6,4

```
class Pirate {

public static final  int MAX_ELEMENTS = 5;
String [] coordinateArray;
int position;

PrintStream out;

Pirate() {
    out = new PrintStream(System.out);
}


void addInOrginalArray (String coordinateRowInput) { 
    coordinateArray = new String [MAX_ELEMENTS];
    int position = 0; 
    coordinateArray[position] = coordinateRowInput;

    for (int i = 0; i < coordinateArray.length; i++) {
        position += 1;
        System.out.println(i + "\t" + coordinateArray [i]);
}

} 

void start() {

    Scanner fileScanner = UIAuxiliaryMethods.askUserForInput().getScanner(); 

    fileScanner.useDelimiter("=");

    while (fileScanner.hasNext()) {
        String coordinateRowInput = fileScanner.next();
        Scanner coordinateInputScanner = new Scanner(coordinateRowInput);
        addInOrginalArray(coordinateRowInput);
    } 
}   

public static void main(String[] argv) {
new Pirate().start();
}
}
```

Comment: The first thing you do in addInOriginalArray() is replace the existing coordinateArray with a new one, so every time you call it, any old information in that array is lost.

Comment: I'd also note that in Java, in almost all cases it's better to use a List than an Array. It has code to handle adding, removing, and rearranging so you don't have to write any to do that.

Comment: What does the input string - `5,4 4,5 8,7=6,3 3,2 9,6 4,3=7,6=9,8=5,5 7,8 6,5 6,4` - mean?